# Convert MultiIndex into columns Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, transformation, multi-index

I would like to know how to perform the below transformation in a pandas dataframe. I have no idea how to tackle this. The idea is to take the index level 0 and set it as level 0 column with the rest of the columns place into the appropiated main column

[image: initial dataframe]

[image: final dataframe]

Comment: Welcome to SO! what did you try so far? did you do any research? Can you add the data of the dataframe as text in the question so people can use it? FYI [how to ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this reshaping the dataframe using `set_index`, `unstack` and `swaplevel`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1, append=True)\
           .reset_index(level=1)\
           .rename(columns={'level_1':'ident'})\
           .unstack(0)\
           .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)\
           .sort_index(axis=1)
df_out
```

Output:

```
          A                        B                         C                 
       city ident population    city ident population     city ident population
1        NY     1      57578  London     4     543534   Berlin     7    5257537
2        LA     2    8767867   Paris     5      25725   Madrid     8      53755
3  Valencia     3    8767678  Beijin     6     275275  Belfast     9     354354
```